# Posting two forms at once

Tags: html, paypal

I have two forms on my page - an item selection form that interacts with a database of mine, and a quantity selection form that interacts with Paypal.

One has post to "", the other posts to Paypal's site. I want them both to post at once, but only when the Paypal button is pressed, so that my code runs, and the page goes to Paypal.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least a couple options.

You could:

1. Spawn an AJAX request to post data to your server, then submit the paypal form as the success callback of this AJAX request.
2. Submit the form to your server, and have the response of the form submission redirect to a page which knows how to submit a post request to Paypal.

Of the two, I would recommend 1) as you can easily control the UI the user is experiencing and you do not create oddly related components on your server.

For 1, note that test.php is an absolute or relative url to your serverside script, testform is the id of the form you want to submit to your server, and your_paypal_form is the id of the form you want to submit to paypal:

```
$('#paypalButton').click(function(){
   $.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize(), function(){
      $('#your_paypal_form').submit();
   });
 });
```

Comment: How would I go about doing the first option?

Comment: Yes, I have jQuery running on the page in question. I'm pretty new to it, though.

Comment: If I had no server-side script before how would I show that in the code?

Comment: What do you mean?  If your form is "an item selection form that interacts with a database of mine" than that form must communicate with some serverside script...

Comment: There's a lot of PHP code but that's on the same page, it interacts with a MySQL database through that PHP code. But everything is contained in one file, and the first form's has action="".

Comment: Oh I see, put the php code that is designed to interact with the MySQL database after receiving a post from the form in a different file and have the AJAX request post to that.

Comment: That's what I did, I believe it may work now. However, the page automatically runs the post request to the Paypal site as soon as it loads. So when you go on the page, it is as if it redirects to the Paypal page. How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: The code I showed you above should be run as an event handler to some action the user takes.  For example, the click event of some button.  It should not just be inlined on the page and run at page load (which I think is what is happening for you right now.)

Comment: Let's say the Paypal button has the id="paypalButton". How do I make the code run on the click of that button?

Comment: $('#paypalButton').click(  function(){$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize(), function(){
     $('#your_paypal_form').submit();
})});

Comment: Hmm. I have your code running but it isn't working. If I do a regular post using the existing submit button for the first form, it works fine. The Paypal button by itself also works fine. But when I try to do what I want with the two forms, no posting occurs of the first form. Here is my current JS code - http://slexy.org/view/s2IrAsI4h0

Comment: Do you see the XHR request getting issued in an http proxy such as the Net tab in Firebug or Fiddler2?

Comment: If you could provide the php/html it would make this much easier.

Comment: Here's the html - http://slexy.org/view/s21isYpy7I && here is the post.php - http://slexy.org/view/s208WfbKso

Comment: Try changing the paypalButton element to an actual image tag instead of an input of type image.  Everything else looks good -- you should also see if an AJAX request is being issued when you click the button, and step through the JavaScript using a JavaScript debugger like Firebug for Firefox.